# Сортировка данных "горкой" - чтобы столбец с максимальной суммой оказался в центре

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Необходимо отсортировать данные в таблице так, чтобы столбцы в которых больше значение были в центре таблицы, а столбцы с меньшими значениями шли от центра влево и вправо. Получается, в самом крайнем правом и самом левом столбце будет наименьшее значение.

Пример таблицы, по столбцам идет ID, по строкам время, ниже указал сумму по значениям столбцов:

```
    1120    1221    4534    1244    1563    1670    1970
1    0       10      20      30     40      50      13
2    2       12      0       31     41      51      67
3    3       0       22      0      0       0       0
4    0       16      0       33     43      53      1
5    5       18      24      34     44      0       1
6    6       0       0       35     45      55      100
7    7       22      26      36     0       56      0
8    0       24      27      37     47      57      56
9    9       0       0       34     48      58      0
10   0       28      0       39     49      0       0
11   11      30      30      40     50      60      0
12   12      32      31      41     51      0       0
13   0       0       32      42     52      62      0


сумма:55     192     212    436     510     502     238
```

Пример того, что примерно должно выйти:

```
    1120    4534    1244    1563    1670    1970
1   2       20      30      40      50      13
2   3       0       31      41      51      67
3   0       22      0       0       0       0
4   5       0       33      43      53      1
5   6       24      34      44      0       1
6   7       0       35      45      55      100
7   0       26      36      0       56      0
8   9       27      37      47      57      56
9   0       0       38      48      58      0
10  11      0       39      49      0       0
11  12      30      40      50      60      0
12  0       31      41      51      0       0
13  0       32      42      52      62      0


    55      212     436     510     502     238
```

Предполагаю, что необходимо:

1. Сначала отсортировать по ID (по столбцам), на четные и не четные.
2. Задать центр, где от центра вправо идут допустим нечетные от большего к меньшему.
3. Если четные идут от меньшего к большему, то к центру.

Такая идея, но как реализовать такое, не нашел.

Так же загвоздка в том, что таблица по `ID` всегда разная. Может быть в один день `ID=300`, в другой день `ID=350`.

Часть кода, которая приводет примерно к такой таблице:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\all.csv", low_memory=False)
table = data[["Id","Period","A","B"]]

cols = ["A","B"]

table1=table.eval("D = {}".format("+".join(cols))).drop(columns=cols)

tablefinal = table1.query("'2019-11-11' <= Period < '2019-11-12'")

matrix = pd.pivot_table (tablefinal, index="Period", columns="Id", fill_value=0)

matrix_final = matrix.groupby(np.arange(len(matrix))//5).sum()
```

Comment: Мало исходных данных. каковы критерии "расхождения" значений вправо и влево? покажите пример желаемого результата.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что задача заключается в сортировке одномерного списка - значений наименований столбцов?

Comment: У меня выходит двумерный массив, есть id по столбцам, есть время по строкам и внутри этой матрицы значения.

Comment: Пожалуйста замените картинки на  данные в текстовой форме.

Comment: @0xdb, заменил)

Comment: @Евгений Спасибо! Тогда плюсую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример исходного DataFrame:

```
In [191]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 5)))

In [192]: df
Out[192]:
   0  1  2  3  4
0  3  6  3  1  7
1  0  1  3  1  2
2  6  8  0  8  0

In [193]: df.sum()
Out[193]:
0     9
1    15
2     6
3    10
4     9
dtype: int64
```

Решение:

```
In [194]: sorted_sums = df.sum().sort_values().index.tolist()

In [195]: idx = sorted_sums[len(sorted_sums)%2::2] + sorted_sums[::-2]

In [196]: res = df.loc[:, idx]
```

Результат:

```
In [197]: res
Out[197]:
   0  3  1  4  2
0  3  1  6  7  3
1  0  1  1  2  3
2  6  8  8  0  0

In [198]: idx
Out[198]: [0, 3, 1, 4, 2]
```

Comment: попробовал под свой код сделать, выдает ошибку

raise AttributeError("module 'pandas' has no attribute '{}'".format(name))
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'sum'

Comment: @Евгений, вы делаете `pd.sum()` - у меня в ответе `df.sum()`... Я надеюсь вы не переопределили `df = pd`??

Comment: я как начал изучать, всегда использовал pd.

У меня стоит так: 

**from PIL import Image, ImageDraw**
**import numpy as np**
**import pandas as pd**

Comment: разобрался, df в моем случае сама таблица matrix_final, сейчас переписываю код, спасибо)

Comment: получилось, спасибо огромное) картинка преобразилась, правда теперь нужно работать над дизайном, дабы легче было воспринимать информацию с нее